# why does my jvm crash after calling clip.open

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi, javasound

On a raspberry pi zero I call a java subprogram playsound(String pSoundDateiName) and it works for the first two times. the third time i call it (from main program) the jvm crashes.
I found out that the call of play.open is the problem, this command will lead to the crash.
Has anyone an idea why?
Or another solution?

```
public static void playsound(String pSoundDateiName){
try {
   File in = new File(pSoundDateiName);
   AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
   Clip play = AudioSystem.getClip();
   play.open(audioInputStream);
   play.start();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   play.drain();
   play.close();
   audioInputStream.close();            
}  catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   };
};

Actual result after the third call:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb651e5fc, pid=12133, tid=2911761520
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x1c05fc]
```

I tried a newer java version but with same result: (but now we have a "DefNewGeneration::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)")

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb64d2b98, pid=1001, tid=0xb3ed7470
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x1c4b98]   DefNewGeneration::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)+0xc
```

I found file "hs_err_pid1001.log" and tried to understand the content but its very difficult to read

What can I do with such a problem?
If there is a bug in jvm what can i do?

I did now a complete new minimalistic installation of raspberry stretch (lite), used the newest version of java (192) and the problem is the same.
But I recognized I can do more calls of the subprogram until it crashes. Also when i changed the memory usage (memory split) of the system then the number of subprogram calls (until crash) changes.
I think there is no "cleaning" of the memory usage in my program.
Can i force java to do such a "cleaning"?
Any ideas else?

I have now a workaround for my problem. I start the main program with the java call "java -Xms128M -Xmx256M ..." that gives me more available memory and more than one hundred calls of the subprogram until crash. Additionally my raspberry will boot automatically every night.
I know that this is no perfect solution but it works.
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Crashes like this are usually due to JVM bugs. You have update 65 of Java 8, the current update is 191

Comment: Usually when Java crashes, you get a a hotspot crash file that starts with `hs_err_pid `. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/felog.html#fatal_error_log_vm to find the crash log. The document also offers help, when trying to interpret the log.

Comment: I'm curious what your end goal is. Do you wish to play this cue multiple times? Concurrently? Clips are meant to be loaded just once, held in memory, and repositioned if they are to be replayed. Do you get the same error with SourceDataLine (might be a better choice, as it consumes much less memory)?

Comment: The main program is a bell system and everytime someone rings at the door the subprogram is called. I will try your suggestion and use SourceDataLine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your audioInputStream object after using it with `audioInputStream.close()`.

Comment: I changed to            ...play.drain();
           play.close();
           audioInputStream.close();          
        }  catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException ex) {... but same problem

Comment: The suggestion is not unreasonable. Closing releases resources that for all we know are limited with this system. Many new users of Java sound don't realize that opening an AudioInputStream consumes resources. (+1 to negate the negative eval)

Comment: Yes I recognized that this was missing in my code and I changed it in that way.But it changes the result in no way, the problem is somewhere else.